# Ubuntu High CPU usage because of mysql.pid

Tags: 18.04, mysql, cpu-load

Ubuntu High volume cpu usage Cant find why mysql.pid use 95% of my cpu
Machine Spec:

> 6 vCore /16 GB Memory / 320 GB Disk / SFO2 - Ubuntu 18.04 x64

**Here is my `mysqld.cnf`**

```
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
sql_mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size         = 128M
max_allowed_packet      = 268435456
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 50
max_heap_table_size     = 256M
tmp_table_size          = 256M
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#thread_concurrency     = 10
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 5G
innodb_log_file_size    = 650M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 5
innodb_file_per_table=1
open_files_limit=50000
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_io_capacity=1000
innodb_old_blocks_time=1000
innodb_open_files=5000
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
read_buffer_size=256K
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K
query_cache_size=512M
query_cache_limit=5M
join_buffer_size=4M
sort_buffer_size=4M
table_open_cache=4500
table_definition_cache=4000
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#slow_query_log     = 1
#slow_query_log_file    = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem
```

[image]

Comment: What make you think that mysql.pid is cause of high cpu usage? Please update your question with the output of `top`.

Comment: It happen suddenly if there is one 10 visitor

Comment: I have added top screenshot @SorenA

Comment: Please add a top screenshot A) before your SHUTDOWN; of MySQL and B) another top screenshot when MySQL is not running, C) start your MySQL and post a third top screenshot.  By carefully looking at PID id's we will be able to tell leftovers from earlier failures to SHUTDOWN; for an orderly shutdown of MySQL.